# Variable type for an object

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

I am new to C++ and I was playing around with encapsulation of objects. My problem arises when I try to make an object that can take another object into the constructor.
I am not sure what type of value I should give the variable when I initially assign it at the top of the object. I tried `void` and `int` but neither seem to work. here is my code:

```
class NewTest {
    int value;
public:
    NewTest() {
        value = 5;
    }

    int return_value() {
        return value;
    }
};

class OuterTest {
    int object;
public:
    OuterTest(int input) {
        object = input;
    }

    int return_object_value() {
        cout << object.return_value() << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    NewTest test_new;
    OuterTest outer_new(int test_new);
    outer_new.return_object_value();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that you are already declaring variables in `main()` with object types. Parameters and member variables are no different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to declare a variable of the type of your custom class:

```
 #include <iostream>

class ClassA
{

public:
    //This function just returns the name of the class
    const char* getName() const
    {
        return "ClassA";
    }
};

class ClassB
{
    //variable of type ClassA
    ClassA myOwnObjA;

    public:
        //Constructor
        ClassB(ClassA objA)//I just receive objects of type ClassA ;)
        {
            myOwnObjA = objA;
            std::cout << "The name of the class of my object is: " << myOwnObjA.getName() << '\n';
        }
};

int main()
{
    ClassA objA;

    ClassB objB(objA);

    return 0;
}
```